# How complete and mature is PyWin32?

Tags: python, windows

I am considering utilizing Python for creating an application. The purpose of this application is solely to interact with the Windows API. My question, therefore, is: Is PyWin32 mature and complete enough to be relied upon, or would I be better off doing this in C++? The reasons why I wanted to use Python are:

1. Easier access to coders
2. Easier to develop and maintain Python code than C++ code

I saw that we are currently on Build 242 (or something) of PyWin32, which gives me exactly no idea about the maturity. I can see that there has been releases since 2004, though, but that does not really say a lot either.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can see [here](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/) that there have been changes during the last 7 days. So it seems still pretty active. I don't know about the stability.

Comment: If you're looking for Windows-only Python solution, you might want to take a look at IronPython, it's Python for the .Net virtual machine. So the Windows API bindings should also be there.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff. Thank you, but I cannot rely upon .Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I used PyWin32 to do a lot of automation a couple years back.  I found it to be complete and well written and maintained.  I also found that is was more complete then any .Net mappings to the win32 api at that time.

Comment: Yes, pywin32 works great.

Comment: After PyWin32 that lets you call Win32API or Dispatch based COM object, the natural would be to use comtypes http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/ for custom interface COM object. Afterward, you may found the need to use an even more deeper integration to Windows call DLLs using ctypes http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/

Comment: @swdev, Thanks for the information. I was actually wondering about when you would use `comtypes` over `pywin32` as it seems `Dropbox is using `comtypes` rather than `pywin32`: https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/10/adventures-with-comtypes/

Comment: what is your opinion about `IronPython` or `ExcelDNA`? I know they are based on `.NET`, which is supposed to superced `COM`, but it seems that `COM` based python extensions such as `pywin32` and `comtypes` are much more popular than `Iron Python`. When would you use `IronPython` (`.NET` based interface) over `pywin32/comtypes`(COM based interface)?